# Storing an arbitrary action to be executed upon completion of an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, callback

The flow for my application, for non-logined users, looks like this:

```
1) non-logined user does a given action that requires login (arbitrary)
2) dialog appears for non-logined user and he logins without any refreshing of the page
3) collecting of additional information if it is new user
3) the given action should be executed
```

How can i do so? I believe it can be done with carefully structured callbacks. Part of the tricky part is that there are a range of potential actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the action as a callback in a variable:

```
var callback = function() { alert ("You are logged in."); };
```

When a non-logged user attempts to execute this action, by clicking a button, or whatever, your application should pass the callback as an argument to the log-in function like this:

```
show_login_form(callback);
```

... where `callback` is what will be executed on a succesful login. Putting it all together:

```
    var callback = function() { alert ("You are logged in."); };
    if (loggedIn)
         callback();
    else
         show_login_form(callback);
```

Just be sure you do some kind of server side validation, as my example is simplistic and easily hacked.

Comment: Thanks! The general idea works. I have implemented it, tho the way i executed the click event seems hackish - can u take a look here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692288/elegantly-passing-an-click-event-through-multiple-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged ruby-on-rails, so I guess this is going to be a rails app. Are you planning on implementing your own authentication and login system or are you going to use a gem/plugin. I ask because I wouldn't have thought the range of actions would be the tricky part if the actions were all defined in the/a controller. For example with [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) adding:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

in the controller would ensure that all the actions would require a login. This can be refined further using :except like

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
```

With that in mind we only really need to think about the ajax parts. You could perhaps achieve this using js.erb templates and using respond_to in the method, for example

```
def log_in
   respond_to do |f|
     # gracefully fallback!
     f.html { redirect_to new_user_session_path }
     # or do something snazy..
     f.js
   end
end
```

The hard part might actually be getting the ajax log in part working, but hopefully what I've said might help the thought process.

Ryan Bates has done a good screencast on jQuery with Rails but I can't post the link...

Comment: Thanks Ben! Good ideas, tho i am trying to do everything in javascript and minimizing the server side logic. my solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692288/elegantly-passing-an-click-event-through-multiple-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [taconite plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/taconite/) for jQuery. There was a thread on this and Ruby, but it seems to have disappeared except from [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GXL_goLs_JUJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/3004371/rails-need-a-helping-hand-to-finish-this-jquery-ajax-problem+jquery+taconite+ruby&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a).

Comment: thanks peter! This sounds great, but it is too heavy for me. I have implemented the solution this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692288/elegantly-passing-an-click-event-through-multiple-callbacks